# mysql combine multiple columns from multiple tables in one column

Tags: mysql, view

So assume that I have two tables (table 1 and table 2) 
each table has two columns (id, number) as following

```
table 1

+-----+------------+
|  id |   number   |
+-----+------------+
|  1  |   value1   |
+-----+------------+

table 2
+-----+------------+
|  id |   number   |
+-----+------------+
|  2  |   value2   |
+-----+------------+
```

And what I am looking to, is to select all ids and numbers in just two columns to create a new view

```
+-----+------------+
|  id |   number   |
+-----+------------+
|  1  |   value1   |
+-----+------------+
|  2  |   value2   |
+-----+------------+
```

Comment: You are not new to this site, UNION is very basic sql, try do search on your own next time.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, number FROM table1 
UNION ALL
SELECT id, number FROM table2
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use union all or union for unique values as per below-

```
select id,number from tabl1 
union all 
select id,number from tabl2;
```